# Group by Tag elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").length // 8
```

How to count number of each tag name (similar to GROUP BY in SQL) to get object like this:

```
{
    html: 1
    head: 1
    body: 1
    p: 2
    div: 3
}
```

I can get result with many lines of code, but maybe it is possible to do this only in couple lines of code?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tagName` property of the returned [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and count

```js
var count = {};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function (a) {
    count[a.tagName] = (count[a.tagName] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: *double facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with,

```js
var result = {};

[...document.getElementsByTagName("*")].forEach(function(itm) {
  var tag = itm.tagName;
  this[tag] = this[tag] || 0;
  this[tag]++;
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

If your environment doesn't support spread operator, then convert the nodeList to an array manually before using forEach over that. Or we could write it with a traditional `for()` loop.

```js
var result = {}, tag;
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
  tag = elems[i].tagName;
  result[tag] = result[tag] || 0;
  result[tag]++;
}

console.log(result);
```